# how does the manifest for chrome extensions work?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, manifest

I made an extension for google chrome but I don't like what the market put as a warning :(

This extension may have access to:

> Your data on every website
>
> Your history data

the manifest:

```
{
  "name": "extension name",
  "description": "description cool super description.",
  "version": "1.0",
  "permissions": [ "tabs", "http://*/*", "https://*/*" ],
  "browser_action": {
      "default_icon": "icon.png",
      "popup": "popup.html"
  }
}
```

Is there any way to explain to google that I don't access any of this? is just an app to reveal asterisk :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mean "browser history" part then it's a bug on the webstore website which someone should report. This contradicts their own [docs](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/permission_warnings.html) where it says that `tab` permission should raise "Your tabs and browsing activity" warning. (As a reference [this bug report](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=62566) could be used)

"Your data on all websites" is correct one. Their warnings show not what you do, but what you can potentially do.